# Injection safe SQL update query makes no change

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm currently making an ASP site that's backed by an Access database. In the site, I want to let a player purchase some items. They have two forms of currency - gems and herbs.

When a player purchases an item, I want to do three seperate actions -

- Pass the item from their store to their inventory, by changing the relevant boolean in the `ItemPlayerConnection` Table
- Reduce the "Gems" integer from their currency according to their purchase
- Reduce the "Herbs" integer from their currency, also according to what they're buying.

Thus, I'm trying to construct 3 different queries - The first one should look like so:

```
UPDATE ItemPlayerConnection
SET Inventory=TRUE
WHERE 
Player=PlayerNameHere 
AND Item=ItemIDHere
```

In order to move the item from the store to the inventory. The second and third ones are similar, the only difference is gems and herbs - they should look like so:

```
UPDATE Player
SET CurrencyNameHere=(CurrencyNameHere-ItemPriceHere)
WHERE 
Owner=PlayerNameHere
```

So i've tried the following code:

```
static public void Purchase(string player, int itemID, int herbPrice, int gemPrice)
    {
        OleDbCommand command1 = GenerateConnection(
            "UPDATE ItemPlayerConnection SET Inventory=TRUE WHERE Player=@player AND Item=@itemID");
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player", player);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemID", itemID);

        OleDbCommand command2 = GenerateConnection(
            "UPDATE Player SET Herbs=(Herbs-@herbPrice) WHERE Owner=@player");
        command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@herbPrice", herbPrice);
        command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player", player);

        OleDbCommand command3 = GenerateConnection(
            "UPDATE Player SET Gems=(Gems-@gemPrice) WHERE Owner=@player");
        command3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gemPrice", gemPrice);
        command3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player", player);

        command3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

And with breakpoints, I saw the queries - they look fine , yet, although the herbs and gems are changed, the item is not passed from the shop to the inventory. These raise no syntax error -

What is my error?

Comment: Have you tried running the queries as stand-alone to see if they work?

Comment: So the last two queries ran ok and the first not, that's right?

Comment: @Izzy I set a player name to an existing one - Muser, and it asks me to provide a value for it. I believe that is wrong... what did I miss?

Comment: @RubensFarias yes, They all run together so Im keeping them there in case they have something to do with it.

Comment: So, actually, you don't have an runtime error, that's right? I'm afraid that points to your business rules -- we can't know how "to pass the item from the shop to the inventory"

Comment: @RubensFarias Well, passing an item from the shop to the inventory is a metter of changing the `Inventory` boolean in the "ItemPlayerConnection" table, as I thought my query does. There's probably something wrong with it... Notice - I set a player name to an existing one - Muser, and it asks me to provide a value for it. Do you know why could that happen?

Comment: Sorry, I would need to understand more about your program to help fix this bug; I made some suggestions on my answer, but I'm afraid I can't go any further. =/

Comment: @RubensFarias What can I provide you with that will help you to understand?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine and you probably have a business error, but I want to help with something else:

- `AddWithValue` only requires parameter name and value, not a type;
- You should name correctly the parameters, as that will make easier to maintain your code
- You should consider encapsulate all those commands in one database transaction, make they work as a atomic unit; this isn't in the code below

You modified code would be:

```
static public void Purchase(string player, int itemID, int herbPrice, int gemPrice)
{
    OleDbCommand command1 = GenerateConnection(
        "UPDATE ItemPlayerConnection SET Inventory=TRUE WHERE Player=@player AND Item=@itemID");
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player", player);
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemID", itemID);

    OleDbCommand command2 = GenerateConnection(
        "UPDATE Player SET Herbs=(Herbs-@herbPrice) WHERE Owner=@player");
    command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@herbPrice", herbPrice);
    command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player", player);

    OleDbCommand command3 = GenerateConnection(
        "UPDATE Player SET Gems=(Gems-@gemPrice) WHERE Owner=@player");
    command3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gemPrice", gemPrice);
    command3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player", player);

    command3.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I've changed the code, thank you - now it's more understand-able. I'll edit the question soon. I'm not giving you the checkmark though, as it is not the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apperently you guys had no chance, it was my bad. Another function, which was triggered by the button click, sent the ItemID - apperently, I used the wrong method to get it, and I sent bad values - thus , the query executted, the syntax was correct, but since there are no items with the IDs i sent - nothing happened. I figured that out by setting breaking points and looking at the parameter values. Now let's have a glass, you and me, [for many stupid mistakes. :)](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/a/alberteins100015.html)

Answer (score -5):

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlConnection cmd = new SqlConnection();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.SelectCommand = con.CreateCommand();
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText="UPDATE ItemPlayerConnection SET Inventory=TRUE WHERE Player="+player+" AND Item="+itemID);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: OP is using Access DB as clearly mentioned in the question. Plus your query is open to sql injection

Comment: I mentioned in the title - I want to keep the injection-safe structure which AddWithValue provides. Besides, that's quite similar to what I am trying to do right now, just for SQL instead of access...